# How to write the stopping condition in quick sort in assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, quicksort, masm, irvine32

I am trying to implement quick sort in assembly.
I can't implement the return statement when the stopping condition is true as i can do in C# or any other high language.
Help will be appreciated !

Here is my code:

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc
    Len EQU 8
.data
    Numbers byte 5,6,4,7,11,2,9,1
    Sorted byte Len dup(?)
    Index_Pivot dword ?
    Element_Pivot byte ?
    Greater byte Len dup(-1)
    Less byte Len dup(-1)
    Temp dword ?
    Temp2 dword ?
.code
Generate_Random PROC
    Mov eax,ebx
    CALL randomrange
    ret
Generate_Random ENDP
;-----------------------------

Quick_Sort PROC
    CMP ebx,1
        JLE Next
    CALL Generate_Random
    MOV Index_Pivot,eax
    ADD esi,eax
    MOV Temp2,eax
    MOV al,[esi]
    MOV Element_Pivot,al
    MOV byte ptr[esi],' '
    SUB esi,Temp2
    ;-------------------------
    MOV ecx,ebx
    JMP Do_calc
    Continue::

    MOV Temp,edx

    MOV esi,OFFSET Less
    MOV ebx,Temp
    CALL Quick_Sort

    Next:
    ret
Quick_Sort ENDP
;-------------------------------------
Do_calc:
        MOV ebx,0
        MOV edx,0
        ;MOV ecx,Len
        L:
            MOV al,Element_Pivot
            CMP byte ptr[esi],' '
                JE Next
            CMP [esi],al
                JG Move_Greater
                MOV al,[esi]
                MOV Less[edx],al
                INC edx  ; for less array
                JMP Next
                Move_Greater:
                    MOV al,[esi]
                    MOV Greater[ebx],al
                    INC ebx   ; for greater array
            Next:
            INC esi
        LOOP L
    jmp Continue


;-----------------
main PROC
    MOV esi,OFFSET Numbers
    MOV ebx,Len
    CALL Quick_Sort

    MOV edi,OFFSET Sorted

    MOV edi,OFFSET Sorted
    MOV ecx,LENGTHOF Sorted
    lo:
        mov eax,0
        mov al,[edi]
        call writeint
        INC edi
    LOOP lo
    CALL crlf



    exit
main ENDP

END main
```

Comment: This would be a better question if you included at least the section of code where you're trying to code the stop condition.  Having just a link to pastebin is not how we do things on SO.

Comment: Try to look iterative quicksort

Comment: Try to add your code directly to your question. Avoid use of external link because they may be unavailable with time

Comment: @AlessandroChiarotto i can't use iterative just divide and conquer method

Comment: @HocineDJEMAI
it was a try to view my code in a more readable way

Comment: If you look in interned you can find iterative quicksort using while and stack without any sort of recursion.

Comment: @AlessandroChiarotto the task to use divide and conquer method not iterative method

Comment: @MahmoudAnwer - This doesn't look like quicksort. Do you have a working example of quicksort in some other language like C? If not, take a look at the pseudo-code in [wiki quicksort article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort). The assembly code needs to push working variables onto the stack. The example code is using index, Temp, and Temp2, which will get overwritten during recursion. There should be two self recursive calls to quicksort. If you look at wiki article, you can change (A, lo, hi) to (A+lo, hi+1-lo), to use ptr to array and length. Why are you writing ' ' onto the pivot?

Comment: @MahmoudAnwer - The code already has a stopping condition, the check for EBX <= 1 where it just jumps to the return.

Comment: @rcgldr yeah but in high language i return something like list or array everytime the stopping condition is true. i can't do this here

Comment: @rcgldr i don't know what is the equivalent way in assembly to return array or list everytime the stopping condition is true

Comment: @MahmoudAnwer - normally quicksort sorts an array in place, so it doesn't return anything. The partition function usually returns a pivot index.

Comment: @rcgldr this is my quick sort code in c#.it returns a list of integers
http://pastebin.com/QLsTeXdV

Comment: @MahmoudAnwer - Your c# quick sort code is not a conventional quick sort. Most of the operations seem like linked list operations, but then it indexes to get the pivot. I answered with an example quick sort code for an array of integers.

Answer (score 0):

Your code already has a stopping condition. To return a value or a pointer to a list, you usually just put the value or the pointer to a list in eax and return.

In response to the OP's unusual implementation of a c# quick sort, here is a c# example of a single function Hoare partition scheme quick sort:

```
        static public void Quicksort(int [] a, int lo, int hi)
        {
            if (lo >= hi)
                return;
            int p = a[(lo + hi) / 2];
            int i = lo, j = hi;
            i--;                        // partition
            j++;
            while (true)
            {
                while (a[++i] < p) ;
                while (a[--j] > p) ;
                if (i >= j)
                    break;
                int t = a[i];
                a[i] = a[j];
                a[j] = t;
            }
            Quicksort(a, lo, j);        // recurse
            Quicksort(a, j + 1, hi);
        }
```

Comment: While this is wonderful code, I think the OP specifically asked how to implement a return style approach...  I'm pretty sure he didn't ask for C# code.

Comment: @DavidHoelzer - From the OP's comment made about 4 hours before this comment: "this is my quick sort code in c#. It returns a list of integers " .

Comment: Read it again. He says he knows how to do it in c# but doesn't know how to mimic in assembly.

Comment: @DavidHoelzer - his c# example is not a conventional quick sort, using mostly linked list type operations, but also indexes into an array. So I posted a conventional c# quick sort example. Waiting for the OP to repsond.

Comment: @rcgldr - Thanks a lot, but i can't understand what is the issue with my code in C#. I can use any data structure list or array or anything i want.

Comment: @rcgldr - The steps of Quick Sort using D&C technique as i know are
1 - Select a pivot , and you can select it using many methods and i do this part by selecting it randomly.
2 - Is to divide the elements into two parts "smaller than" and i put it before the pivot element and the second part is "greater than" and i put it after the pivot element.
3 - Then solving the two part "smaller than" and "greater than" in the same manner and it's called the Conquer step.
i think your code is also right but you use the middle method to select the pivot element unlike me i used the random method.

Comment: Sorry i can't understand this part you have said "To return a value or a pointer to a list, you usually just put the value or the pointer to a list in eax and return." if you can show it by a short example, i will appreciated.

Comment: @MahmoudAnwer - the example quicksort I used is a void function, so it doesn't return anything. Since it's a Hoare partition scheme, the "pivot" is included in one of the two parts when an array is split, usually the left part: quicksort(arr, low, pivot), quicksort(arr, pivot+1, high) unlike Lomuto partition scheme which doesn't include the pivot in either part, quicksort(arr, low, pivot-1), quicksort(arr, pivot+1, high).

Comment: @MahmoudAnwer - "return value in eax". You already have an example that uses this in your code. The code calls Generate_Random which in turn calls randomrange, which returns a random value in eax, and then Generate_Random just returns, leaving the value in eax, and then the calling code stores that value into Index_Pivot using the instruction  |  MOV Index_Pivot,eax | .